# UISplitView in Portrait - iPAD

Tags: ipad, uisplitview

How to create Split Over Screen in iPad. I need to develop application which is in portrait view. I need to use Split Over screen view in my application using Portrait View. Please help me to do so.

Comment: Is this Possible to have UISplitView in iPad at portrait view

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Matt Gemmell's MGSplitViewController

http://mattgemmell.com/source

It allows you to use a splitter view in any orientation.